# read json object file in java using gson keep getting null

Tags: java, json, null, gson

I keep getting `null` when I try to read.

json file

```
{
  "team": {
   "name": "john 1",
   "id": "12345"
    }
 }
```

Trying to do it by POJO

```
public class Team {

    private String name;
    private String id;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

My main

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new 
    FileReader("C:/Users/John/Desktop/back.json"));

    Team test = gson.fromJson(br, Team.class);

    System.out.println(getName());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to above JSON structure you should have POJO with property `team`

```
public class Response {

  private Team team

  //getters and setters
   }
```

and `Team` POJO

```
public class Team {

  private String name;
  private String id;

  // getters and setters
  }
```

In `Main` class

```
Response test = gson.fromJson(br, Response.class);  //from this get Team
Team team = test.getTeam();
```

Comment: is there anyway to combine Response and Team into one class?

Comment: at least can you use nested static class? @jovan, and you can do this into one class by using some external libraries or custom deserializer